# Flask-SQLAlchemy db.commit() changes value of field

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm building a simple app in Flask and having difficulty with making the database behave properly while using Flask-SQLAlchemy.  Here's my models.py:

```
from spot import plate
from spot import db
import flask.ext.whooshalchemy as whooshalchemy

class Country(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    country_name = db.Column(db.String(64), unique = True)
    codes = db.relationship('Code', backref='country', lazy='dynamic')

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<%r>' % (self.country_name)

class Code(db.Model):
    __searchable__ = ['scramble']

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    scramble = db.Column(db.String(64), db.ForeignKey('country.id'))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<%r>' % (self.scramble)

whooshalchemy.whoosh_index(plate, Code)
```

I'm trying to create some test data to see if the relationship works as I expect it to, but for some reason, when I create a new Code and commit it to the database, something is overwriting the value of my scramble field to "1", as follows:

```
>>> from spot.models import Country, Code 
>>> from spot import db
>>> c = Country(country_name="Testingstan")
>>> cd = Code(scramble="TS", country=c)
>>> cd.scramble
'TS'
>>> db.session.add(c)
>>> c.country_name
'Testingstan'
>>> db.session.add(cd)
>>> cd.scramble
'TS'
>>> db.session.commit()
>>> c.country_name
u'Testingstan'
>>> cd.scramble
u'1'
>>> for code in c.codes:
...     print code
...
<u'1'>
```

So I'm feeling confident that the association between the country and the code is being made properly, but why is SQLAlchemy overwriting my scrambles but not my country name?  I pulled up the database in a sqlite database browser, and it's showing me the same thing.  What have I set up incorrectly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `Code` model you defined the `scramble` field as your foreign key for the relationship with `Country`. That makes SQLAlchemy take ownership of the field and use it to store the id of the associated country.

I think what you want is this instead:

```
class Code(db.Model):
    __searchable__ = ['scramble']

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    scramble = db.Column(db.String(64))
    country_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('country.id'))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<%r>' % (self.scramble)
```

In this way you get your `scramble` field to yourself, but you also give SQLAlchemy the foreign key it needs.